# Is it possible to merge two time series in one?

Tags: r, merge

I've been trying to merge two ts objects, the second one starts exactly one period after the next one.
For example, take the following two time series

```
ts1<-ts(c(1:12),star=c(2014,1),freq=12)
ts2<-ts(c(13:24),star=c(2015,1),freq=12)
```

As you can see, both of them match perfectly in order to make a single ts out of this two ts objects. I thought the logical answer would be the rbind() function. But it makes a matrix out of them, as follows...

```
> rbind(ts1,ts2)
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
ts1    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12
ts2   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21    22    23    24
```

I've tried without success other functions like merge,cbind. Using c() I've managed to get one only timeseries, the main problema is that I lose structure attributes of the original timeseries, this is bad because I'm trying to use the function forecast with the new ts but it gives me  this:

```
Error: variables ... were specified with different types from the fit
```

I would be happy just with being able to add additional observations to a time series. Something like adding the value 13 to ts1 for January,2015 but I haven´t found how to do this either.

I think is funny because I see this as a perfectly natural thing to ask for to a ts object, but I haven´t found any other question that helps me out here. Well let´s hope this is not a too silly question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the xts package which will take care of details for you (for instance even if the series have a gap)

```
library(xts)
ts1<-as.xts(ts(c(1:12),star=c(2014,1),freq=12))
ts2<-as.xts(ts(c(13:24),star=c(2015,1),freq=12))
str(ts3 <- c(ts1, ts2))
# An ‘xts’ object on Jan 2014/Dec 2015 containing:
# Data: int [1:24, 1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
# Indexed by objects of class: [yearmon] TZ: 
# xts Attributes:
# NULL
```

Cheers, Peter

Answer (score 10):

You need to reassign the attributes from the first series.

```
> ts(c(ts1,ts2), start=start(ts1), frequency=frequency(ts1))
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2014   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
2015  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
```

Comment: Thanks! If you´ve asked me I would have sweared I tried that a thousend times.

Comment: I did try to assign the attributes from ts1 to the result of c(ts1,ts2) with `attributes<-` and it failed.

Comment: excuse my ignorance, how do you pass attributes to a ts? and more specifically why did that failed this time?

Comment: It's probably better for your mental health if you just use xts methods.

Answer (score 8):

I think you're looking for something like

```
comb <- ts.union(ts1, ts2)
pmin(comb[,1], comb[,2], na.rm = TRUE)
#     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
#2014   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
#2015  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
```

Comment: I tried that already, i get the same result as by trying cbind() it puts one ts next to the other, fills with NA´s the missing values of each timeseries

Comment: @fake22 Arh, you can then use `pmin` or `pmax`. I've edited my post.

Comment: Didn´t know those functions. That makes it too! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
ts.union(ts1, ts2)
             ts1 ts2
    Jan 2014   1  NA
    Feb 2014   2  NA
    Mar 2014   3  NA
    Apr 2014   4  NA
    May 2014   5  NA
    Jun 2014   6  NA
    Jul 2014   7  NA
    Aug 2014   8  NA
    Sep 2014   9  NA
    Oct 2014  10  NA
    Nov 2014  11  NA
    Dec 2014  12  NA
    Jan 2015  NA  13
    Feb 2015  NA  14
    Mar 2015  NA  15
    Apr 2015  NA  16
    May 2015  NA  17
    Jun 2015  NA  18
    Jul 2015  NA  19
    Aug 2015  NA  20
    Sep 2015  NA  21
    Oct 2015  NA  22
    Nov 2015  NA  23
    Dec 2015  NA  24
```