# How can I combine two time-series in Rstudio?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Code:

```
times_USST <- ts(Final_Com_return$Comp.int_USST, start= 1934-01, frequency = 12)
times_TRSB <- ts(Final_Com_return$Comp.int_TRSB, start= 1934-01, frequency= 12)
```

these two lines of codes makes up two indevidual plots. My problem is combining the two.
we are trying to make both linear and log-scale graphs for stock-index and for our T-bill

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please edit your post to include your data.  The following code will generate a code snippet with 10 random records that you can paste into your original post: dput(dplyr::sample_n(YourDatasetsNameGoesHere, 10)). To use my code, you may need to install dplyr with: install.packages("dplyr")

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944092/is-it-possible-to-merge-two-time-series-in-one) will help you. As described by [Pete Baker](https://stackexchange.com/users/4542036/pete-baker) "You could use the xts package which will take care of details for you (for instance even if the series have a gap)"

```
library(xts)
ts1<-as.xts(ts(c(1:12),star=c(2014,1),freq=12))
ts2<-as.xts(ts(c(13:24),star=c(2015,1),freq=12))
str(ts3 <- c(ts1, ts2))
# An ‘xts’ object on Jan 2014/Dec 2015 containing:
# Data: int [1:24, 1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
# Indexed by objects of class: [yearmon] TZ: 
# xts Attributes:
# NULL
```