# Join time series in R

Tags: r, join, merge, time-series

I would like to create a time series with a monthly interval by extending an already existing time series.

I have "t1" time series:
structure(c(49.25, 49.25, 30, 99.25, 99.25, 100.5, 101,
91.25), .Dim = c(1L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("2021-03-31",
"2022-03-31", "2022-05-31", "2022-09-30", "2022-12-31", "2023-03-31",
"2023-05-31", "2023-09-30")), .Tsp = c(1, 1, 1), class = c("mts",
"ts", "matrix"))

I would like to extend the above series to include monthly observations. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944092/is-it-possible-to-merge-two-time-series-in-one

Comment: @akrun I think that's not duplicate, "t1" time series is not the same length as time series which I'd like to obtain

Comment: You could create a second 't2' dataset with `NA` i.e. `t2 <-  ts(rep(NA, 20), start = c(2021, 03), freq = 1)` and then use the code in that post i.e. with `ts.union`

Comment: @akrun doesnt work, error: time series have different frequency

Comment: Your freq shows it is 1 and that is why I created same frequency of 1.  Please use `dput` to show the example so that we can get the structure correcly

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I edited my post

Comment: @G.Grothendieck should work now

Answer (score 0):

The object in the question is in a strange form.  It consists of 9 separate time series with column names given by character dates.  First extract the character dates and the values into a zoo object with yearmon time class -- yearmon directly represents a year and month without day.  Ensure that it has frequency 12 and convert it to ts class which will have the effect of filling in the missing months.  Finally extend it to the desired date.

```
library(zoo)

z <- zoo(t1[-1], as.yearmon(colnames(t1)[-1]), frequency = 12)
tt <- window(as.ts(z), end = c(2024, 11), extend = TRUE)
tt
```

giving this ts object:

```
        Jan    Feb    Mar    Apr    May    Jun    Jul    Aug    Sep    Oct    Nov    Dec
2021                49.25     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
2022     NA     NA  49.25     NA  30.00     NA     NA     NA  99.25     NA     NA  99.25
2023     NA     NA 100.50     NA 101.00     NA     NA     NA  91.25     NA     NA     NA
2024     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

Note that you can use `View(as.zoo(tt))` to view tt and can use `na.approx(tt, na.rm = FALSE, rule = 2)` to fill in internal NAs with interpolated values and trailing NAs with the last non-NA value.

### Note

The input is shown in the question as:

```
t1 <-  structure(c(49.25, 49.25, 30, 99.25, 99.25, 100.5, 101, 91.25), .Dim = c(1L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("2021-03-31", "2022-03-31", "2022-05-31", "2022-09-30", "2022-12-31", "2023-03-31", "2023-05-31", "2023-09-30")), .Tsp = c(1, 1, 1), class = c("mts", "ts", "matrix"))
```