# R: Merging Two Time Series

Tags: r

I have these two time series data in R:

```
# ts1: 2010-first week until 2019 last week
ts1 <- ts(rnorm(1040, mean = 100, sd = 50), start = c(2010, 1), frequency = 52)

# ts2: 500 new weeks after the end of ts1 (note: I wonder if there was a way to automaticlaly start from end(ts1))
ts2 <- ts(rnorm(500, mean = 150, sd = 60), start = c(2020, 1), frequency = 52)
```

**My Question:** I am trying to merge both of these time series into a single object.

I tried to follow the instructions given here [Is it possible to merge two time series in one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944092/is-it-possible-to-merge-two-time-series-in-one)

```
comb <- ts.union(ts1, ts2)
```

The code ran, but this is not giving the desired result:

```
> head(comb)
Time Series:
Start = c(2000, 1) 
End = c(2000, 6) 
Frequency = 52 
               ts1 ts2
2000.000  37.56999  NA
2000.019  46.10463  NA
2000.038 112.50387  NA
2000.058  94.01130  NA
2000.077  84.95737  NA
2000.096 -16.03819  NA
```

**I am trying to combine these into a single time series object.**

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

- **Note:** In the future, I would like to be able to "break and re-join" this time series at arbitrary points.

For example:

```
#pseudocode : imagine you start with "ts"
ts_a <- ts[, ts$date>2015-01]
ts_b <- ts[, ts$date<2015-01]
ts_recover  = rbind(ts_a, ts_b)
identical(ts, ts_recover)
```

Comment: The first series starts from 2000, the second series starts from 2020, hence the NAs, if this is what's bothering you.

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: the time series overlap for about 10 years but only 10 years after the first one. You want a single time series object: do you want to sum the overlapping time?